# Pass a dynamic 'href' from mdx into NextJs 'Anchor' custom styled component

Tags: next.js, components

I'm trying to access the 'href' data in a markdown  tag through MDX and into a custom styled NextJS component.

At the moment I want someone to be able to write in markdown:

```
[Website](http://www.website.com)
```

and get the data into a custom style component something like this:

```
./components/md/Anchor.tsx 

function Anchor({ hrefProp, text }) {
 
  return <a className="text-blue-600 my-4 text-base" href={hrefProp} target="_blank" rel="noopener">{text}</a>;
}
export default Anchor;
```

The url `'http://website.com'` is getting lost going from mdx to jsx, I'm  only able to tap into the {text}.

Ideally I don't have to change the markdown syntax much at all to achieve this.  Any suggestions?

I thought maybe trying to put the href data through the `meta` or `frontmatter` as a way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried the `href` prop?

Comment: Yes I'm stuck on how to access the ```href``` prop from the MDX - markdown:
```[Website](http://www.website.com)```
I am only getting the text "Website" but the url is getting lost somewhere.

I'd like to do:
```
./components/md/Anchor.tsx 

function Anchor({ hrefProp, text }) {
 
  return <a className="text-blue-600 my-4 text-base" href={hrefProp} target="_blank" rel="noopener">{text}</a>;
}
export default Anchor;
```

Comment: Are you using `@next/mdx` and `@mdx-js/react`?

Comment: Yes I am- sorry we had a holiday weekend here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `@next/mdx` and `@mdx-js/react`, you can access the `href` prop via the `href` prop in your `Anchor` component.

1. Implement styled link component:

```
// components/mdx/Anchor.tsx

import * as React from "react";

export default function Anchor({
  href,
  children,
  ...rest
}: React.JSX.IntrinsicElements["a"]) {
  return (
    <a
      href={href}
      target="_blank"
      rel="noreferer noopener"
      className="text-blue-600 my-4 text-base"
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </a>
  );
}
```

2. Add `MDXProvider` with custom link component to your `_app.tsx`:

```
// pages/_app.tsx

import * as React from "react";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { MDXProvider } from "@mdx-js/react";

import Anchor from "@/components/mdx/Anchor";
import "@/styles/globals.css";

const components = {
  a: Anchor,
};

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <MDXProvider components={components}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </MDXProvider>
  );
}
```

3. Setup `@next/mdx` in `next.config.js`:

```
// next.config.js

const withMDX = require("@next/mdx")({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [],
    rehypePlugins: [],
    providerImportSource: "@mdx-js/react",
  },
});

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  pageExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "md", "mdx"],
};

module.exports = withMDX(nextConfig);
```

Sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stackoverflow-76283549-h1fkf9?file=%2Fcomponents%2Fmdx%2FAnchor.tsx

Comment: Yes this solution works! I had a dummy mistake and didn't import React on the Anchor component . I think it was as simple as the `href` prop you mentioned first off. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to hear this solution worked for you. Feel free to accept this answer.